# Oracle error at dbms_utility

Tags: oracle, triggers, database-connection

The problem occurred when I tried to create a database user with more than 30 characters and then to create a trigger in that (within one script). The user wasn't created as it had more than 30 chars, but somehow the trigger got created. Now I'm not able to login to the database anymore and throws the below exception when my java application tries to connect to this database.

```
 Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory 
 (ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
 ORA-00972: identifier is too long
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_UTILITY", line 833
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SESSION", line 230
ORA-06512: at line 2
)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2303)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2043)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1543)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228)
    ... 95 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL 
level 1
ORA-00972: identifier is too long
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_UTILITY", line 833
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SESSION", line 230
ORA-06512: at line 2

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:389)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:382)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:600)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:445)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:380)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:760)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:401)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:546)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:236)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:257)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2313)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2299)
```

How can this trigger can be deleted or any other ways to rectify this problem?

Script that I executed: (but instead of TESTDB, I previously had more than 30 chars)

```
-- USER SQL
CREATE USER TESTDB IDENTIFIED BY nodba ;


-- ROLES

GRANT "CONNECT" TO TESTDB ;

-- SYSTEM PRIVILEGES
GRANT SELECT ANY TABLE TO TESTDB ;
GRANT SELECT ANY SEQUENCE TO TESTDB ;
GRANT SELECT ANY TRANSACTION TO TESTDB ;
GRANT UPDATE ANY TABLE TO TESTDB ;
GRANT INSERT ANY TABLE TO TESTDB ;
GRANT DELETE ANY TABLE TO TESTDB ;

create role TestRole;

grant TestRole to TESTDB;


ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = TESTDB;

create or replace trigger readonly_logon_trigger
after logon on database
begin
if (dbms_session.is_role_enabled('TestRole')) then
 execute immediate 'alter session set current_schema = MAINDB';
end if;
end;
```

Comment: Can you connect as SYS? Or do you have a DBA who can?

Comment: No, I don't have any dba for this database. I executed the script mentioned at the end  (but instead of TESTDB, I previously gave more than 30 chars)

Comment: So do you have a user called MAINDB? Also, please clarify whether you can connect to the database as SYS (perhaps using SQL`*Plus `connect / as sysdba`?) . Finally, where did you get this script from? And why did you change it to create a user with an illegally long name?

Comment: At first glance there isn't anything in the posted trigger which would cause the error you say you get. So presumably your actual trigger is different, perhaps changing the schema to another illegally long schema name. If you want us to help you must post **the exact code** you're using. Otherwise you're just wasting everybody's time, as I type out these long comments asking for more details.

Comment: @APC you are right. Nothing wrong with that script. I'm getting this error even when I created a new user with CONNECT privilege. It's due to some other reason, I think. I'll figure it out. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: The trigger was added at the system level with more than 30 characters that was causing this problem. It's resolved now.

Answer (score 1):

The trigger was added at the system level with more than 30 characters that was causing this problem. It's resolved now.